# datatable function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my onload function

```
$(document).ready(function() {  


    alert("hi");
            $('#training').dataTable({

                 "aLengthMenu": [100],
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                              null,
                            { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
                              null,
                               ],
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            }); 
            alert("hi");
        } );
```

and here is my table data

```
<table width="100%" align="center"  class="training"  style="margin-top: 10px;" id="training">

                                                                 <tr class="tblRowTitle" height="100">
                                                                    <th  align="center" >SNo.</th>
                                                                    <th  align="center" >User Name</th>
                                                                    <th align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />Unlock</th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                             <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="userList" varStatus="index">
                                                                     <tr class="tblRowB" id="showdata" height="20">

                                                                        <td ><label>${index.count}</label></td>
                                                                        <td align="left">
                                                                            <b><esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>${userList.userName}</esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>
                                                                        </b></td>
                                                                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="unlock" name="unlock" /></td>

                                                             </c:forEach> 
                                                         </table>
```

while i am executing the ready function it is not executing. while i am debugging i got one exception and one one warning message that is

DataTables warning (table id = 'training'): Unexpected number of TD elements. Expected 9 and got 6. DataTables does not support rowspan / colspan in the table body, and there must be one cell for each row/column combination.
common_js.js:1318

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

here is my js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/1.9.4/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

so please let me know where i am doing the mistake 
here i am not getting the pagination and sorting functionality.

Comment: Immediately I can see that you're missing a closing `</tr>` tag

Comment: It's better to re-write your samples and pay attention to white spaces and indentation.

Comment: plus you are including `jquery.dataTables.min.js` and `jquery.dataTables.js` whereas only one is enough! and you don't need `,` at the end here `null,
                            { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
                              null`

Comment: thanks @markpsmith i closed </tr> but no luck.

Comment: thanks Mr rao but still no luck

Comment: why i am getting this 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' plz any one let me know.

Comment: Does the table populate correctly?  ie does it work if you remove the datatables code?

Comment: yes it is means the data population is working fine but i am not getting the functionality of sorting and pagination